# Encoding changing between Django template and view

Tags: python, django, encoding

I am trying to create a dynamic table in a view which will be used to create a Google chart in a template. Starting with the labels, I have trouble to get the correct encoding even by setting # -*- coding : utf-8 -*- at the beginning of my views.py.

When I generate it, the labels list is looking like that when I print it in views.py :

```
 [u'Day', u'305', u'307', u'05', u'95']
```

Therefore, I encode it in utf-8 using :

```
 x.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') for x in items
```

which provides me :

```
 ['Day', '305', '307', '05', '95']
```

But in my template, it is looking like that :

```
  [u&#39;Day&#39;, u&#39;305&#39;, u&#39;307&#39;, u&#39;05&#39;, u&#39;95&#39;],
```

which is obviously not correct and cannot be used to create a Google chart... What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't encoding, it's autoescaping. You can disable it with the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).

But really, since the data is for Javascript, you shouldn't use the string representation of the list at all: you should dump it to JSON and output that instead.

Comment: Many thanks ! It is working :-) As I am a beginner and do not know much about JSON, I am sticking with Django for the moment

Comment: What? I didn't say not to use Django. I said to do `json.dumps(items)` rather than that `x.encode` list comprehension.